# How to perform a pipeline aggregation without returning all buckets in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm using Elasticsearch 2.3 and I'm trying to perform a two-step computation using a pipeline aggregation.
I'm only interested in the final result of my pipeline aggregation but Elasticsearch returns all the buckets information.

Since I have a huge number of buckets (tens or hundreds of millions), this is prohibitive. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to tell Es not to return all this information.

Here is a toy example. I have an index `test-index` with a document type `obj`. `obj` has two fields, `key` and `values`.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://10.10.0.7:9200/test-index/obj' -d '{
  "value": 100,
  "key": "foo"
}'

curl -XPOST 'http://10.10.0.7:9200/test-index/obj' -d '{
  "value": 20,
  "key": "foo"
}'

curl -XPOST 'http://10.10.0.7:9200/test-index/obj' -d '{
  "value": 50,
  "key": "bar"
}'

curl -XPOST 'http://10.10.0.7:9200/test-index/obj' -d '{
  "value": 60,
  "key": "bar"
}'

curl -XPOST 'http://10.10.0.7:9200/test-index/obj' -d '{
  "value": 70,
  "key": "bar"
}'
```

I want to get the average value (over all `key`s ) of the minimum `value` of `obj`s having the same `key`s.
An average of minima.

Elasticsearch allows me to do this:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://10.10.0.7:9200/test-index/obj/_search' -d '{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "key_aggregates": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "key",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "min_value": {
          "min": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "avg_min_value": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "key_aggregates>min_value"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

But this query returns the minimum for every bucket, although I don't need it:

```
{
  "took": 21,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": [

    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "key_aggregates": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "bar",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "min_value": {
            "value": 50
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "foo",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "min_value": {
            "value": 20
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "avg_min_value": {
      "value": 35
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to get rid of all the information inside `"buckets": [...]`? I'm only interested in `avg_min_value`.

This might not seem like a problem in this toy example, but when the number of different `key`s is not big (tens or hundreds of millions), the query response is prohibitively large, and I would like to prune it.

Is there a way to do this with Elasticsearch? Or am I modelling my data wrong?

NB: it is not acceptable to pre-aggregate my data per key, since the `match_all` part of my query might be replaced by complex and unknown filters.

NB2: changing `size` to a non-negative number in my `terms` aggregation is not acceptable because it would change the result.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same issue and after doing quite a bit of research I found a solution and thought I'd share here.

You can use the [Response Filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) feature to filter the part of the answer that you want to receive.

You should be able to achieve what you want by adding the query parameter `filter_path=aggregations.avg_min_value` to the search URL. In the example case, it should look similar to this:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://10.10.0.7:9200/test-index/obj/_search?filter_path=aggregations.avg_min_value' -d '{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "key_aggregates": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "key",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "min_value": {
          "min": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "avg_min_value": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "key_aggregates>min_value"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

PS: if you found another solution would you mind sharing it here? Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a perfect solution. If only we had found this! We didn't find a direct solution to this problem, so we adopted the script aggregation way: building a map whose keys are the field "key" and values the minima over all docs with a given value for field "key"; then aggregating the values of this map. I don't know how the two compare in terms of performance, but in all likelihood your solution should be faster!

Comment: @fgal do you know if "response filtering" circumvents the bucket limitations of elasticsearch? or does it simply truncate/hide the buckets from the output?